# How do I properly include JS libraries using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am quite new to Webpack and I am using it to bundle the assets used for a static website I am creating. This website uses multiple JS files from npm packages like
`fullpage.js` and `parallax.js`. I need to know how I can include these JS files using Webpack.

**What I have tried**

The first option I tried was import JS files via `app.js`

*app.js*

```
import './style.css';
import '../node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.css';


window.$ = require('jquery');
window.$ = require('fullpage.js');
window.$ = require('parallax-js');


require('./index.js');
```

*index.js*

```
var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
    var parallaxInstance = new Parallax(scene,{
        frictionX: 0.1,
        frictionY: 0.1
    });


$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            recordHistory: false,
            scrollBar: true,
        });
    });
```

However, since `parallax-js` is not imported in `index.js`, this doesn't work. Chrome debugger says that `Parallax is not defined -- index.js`

I can overcome this by moving the `require` section to the `index.js` but that doesn't seem clean.

---

My second option was to import these via `webpack.config.js` which seems to me is the correct approach.

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/app.js',
    libs: [
        './node_modules/parallax-js/dist/parallax.js',
        './node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.js'
    ]
  }
}
```

I included both the above created JS files (`libs.js` and `main.js`).
However I am still getting `Parallax is not defined -- index.js`

Which of the above two methods are correct? Is there a better way to achieve this? 
I've read through a lot of documentation and articles but I could not find a proper answer for this very basic question which is why I am posting this here, wondering if I am missing something big.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you're missing something conceptually. You're still trying to use the global context (& window object). Webpack doesn't want you to work that way. Webpack wraps everything up and puts everything in modules.

You need to define your dependencies in every file you use them in. Then, you let webpack figure out how to bundle everything together. It's actually not messy to define dependencies per file; it's the right way of doing things, and the way every other programming language does it.

I would also recommend switching from `require` syntax to `import` syntax, as it helps you to think of it as a declaration, not a function call.

It might be helpful to poke around an ES6 tutorial/project to learn the new syntax and approach. It's a fairly major shift, and particularly difficult for existing JS developers who aren't drawing from experiences in other languages.

You may find this tutorial (or others) helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lziuNMk_8eQ

Comment: Thank you. I did some reading about what you suggested and I modified my `index.js` to have `import Parallax from 'node_modules/parallax-js/dist/parallax.js';`. But do I have to go through my `node_modules` and manually include the paths of every JS library `index.js` depends on?

Comment: Figured that I can use `import Parallax from 'parallax-js';` in `index.js` to import dependecies. But there's another issue, wouldn't importing all these libraries into a single JS file cause any issues like larger size, latency or such issues?

Comment: @DaveHowson well done figuring it out. Absolutely! Most of Webpack's job is to handle that issue. You start by build a graph of all dependencies, then Webpack gives you tools to output everything in the best way possible. It can do this by providing multiple bundle files, referencing CDNs, and much more. It allows you to use many techniques - tree shaking, minification, lazy-loading, and more. `webpack -p` provides nice defaults, but there are a few musts like ExtractTextLoader, and much more. Info generally on the webpack site: https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/